# ¿Cómo declaro una columna double o float en un entitty de TypeORM?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, nestjs, typeorm

Estimados miembros del foro,

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en NestJS con TypeORM y tengo un problema al crear una entidad para una tabla existente en MySQL. La tabla se llama "trd_parametros_moneda" y tiene una columna llamada "porcentaje" que debe ser de tipo double o float.

He intentado lo siguiente para indicarle a TypeORM que la columna es double, pero me da error en la base de datos:

```
@Entity('trd_parametros_moneda') //Nombre de la tabla en MySQL
export class Pliquidador {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  trd_moneda_id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  tipo: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  codigo: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  descripcion: string;

  @Column({ type: "double", precision: 14 })
  porcentaje: number;

}
```

Si quito la definición de la columna porcentaje, me crea la columna como entero, y la necesito como double o float.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
@Column({ type: 'decimal', nullable: false })
subtotal: number
```